# SQL - Delete rows filtered from a query result

Tags: sql, list, delete-row

From this excellent post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755787/9502397 I have understood better now how to Use Join to return a list of results with similar references from different tables.

I have that list as shown in the result after running the Select query

```
select 
    a.OrderDate,
    c.StaffID,
    c.Activate  
from
    tbl_Order a

join tbl_OrderDetails b
    on a.OrderID = b.OrderID

join tbl_Staff c
    on b.StaffID = c.StaffID

where c.Activate = 'False'
```

However, how can I use that result list and delete the those rows from tbl_Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JOIN in DELETE just the same way as how you would use SELECT. Just ensure that the alias in Delete is from the table from which you would like to delete your data from.

```
DELETE a 
FROM
    tbl_Order a
INNER JOIN tbl_OrderDetails b
    on a.OrderID = b.OrderID
INNER JOIN tbl_Staff c
    on b.StaffID = c.StaffID
WHERE c.Activate = 'False'
```

Comment: Wow, neat. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, use `exists`:

```
delete 
from tbl_order a
where exists 
(
select 1 
from tbl_OrderDetails b
inner join tbl_staff c
on b.StaffID = c.StaffID
and c.Activate = 'False'
where b.Order_id = a.Order_id
)
```

Comment: Thank you John! I was hard reading your code at first but I think I understand now. I didn't know you can use `and` with `ON`. I think you must be a very efficient coder :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Common table expression to separate query for resultset and delete data that exists in resultset and desired table:

```
 WITH cte AS
     (
     select 
    a.OrderDate,
    c.StaffID,
    c.Activate  
from
    tbl_Order a

join tbl_OrderDetails b
    on a.OrderID = b.OrderID

join tbl_Staff c
    on b.StaffID = c.StaffID

where c.Activate = 'False'
     )
     Delete
     FROM cte t1
     INNER JOIN tbl_Order t2
     ON t1.Order_id = t2.Order_id;
```

Comment: I had this exact thing in mind when trying to do it, as I feel this would be a safer way than to delete blindly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DELETE FROM WHERE ()IN ()` form, here is how it looks in your code:

```
DELETE FROM
  tbl_Order k
WHERE (k.OrderID) IN (
  SELECT
    a.OrderID 
  FROM
    tbl_Order a
  JOIN tbl_OrderDetails b
    ON a.OrderID = b.OrderID
  JOIN tbl_Staff c
    ON b.StaffID = c.StaffID
  WHERE c.Activate = 'False' )
```

With the SELECT you are extracting the OrderIDs that you want to remove, the WHERE of the DELETE is selecting only the rows with that ID that will be removed.

Comment: Thank you for showing me another way! WHERE IN would be something I need lo learn next :)